# How can I use the value in one cell inside the formula in SAME cell?

Tags: worksheet-function

How can I use the value in one cell inside the formula in SAME cell???

A1 1000
B1 5

I WANT ANSWER IN A1 =1000*B1
                 A2 = 100*B2

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer, you cannot. A cell can either have a value or a formula. The formula can contain a number, but you have to edit the formula to change the value. You cannot see the value first, press enter and let the formula take its process, unless you are willing to go advanced and use VBA macros. Given the nature of VBA macros, (they're hard to grasp if you never programmed before) I am not going into that direction.

You should be looking at dedicating cells for values, and other cells with formulas that link to the value cells. You can then hide the column with these cells so you won't see them, and you can unhide the cells when you need to edit them.

This is basically how Excell is designed to be. (or any other spreadsheet software for that matter)